# Xcode 9 : Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6

Tags: ios, xcode9, xcode9.2, xcode9.1, swift3.2

I am not able to build in xcode 9. It says [Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724897/command-failed-due-to-signal-abort-trap-6). I have tried solutions mentioned in stackoverflow, but none of them worked. As its mentioned, overriding description var gives this error. This is done in third party frameworks like SwiftyJson, RealmSwift on which I dont have control to change.

I have both Objc and swift files in the project. It gives `MergeSwiftModule` issue for the following,

```
1.  While reading from 'targetname'
2.  While deserializing 'NMHTTPResponseSerializer' (ClassDecl #55) in 'targetname'
```

Due to this error I am not able to build project in Xcode 9 and later. Please help.

Comment: Your project is in Swift or Objc ? if ints in Swift which swift version you are using ?

Comment: As I have mentioned, I have both Objc and swift files in the project. Its swift3.2.