# XCODE 9.3 Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6

Tags: xcode, swift4.1, xcode9.3

After updating to Xcode 9.3 I am not able to compile my project. Where as compiling the same code on earlier version of xcode it works.

After lot of investigation i found that there are few functions like in below error -

```
1.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/ankitnigam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Milq-cywzubaffxgpwaeipfxgtfswiuxo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Milq.build/Debug-iphoneos/BN Beta.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AnswerViewController.o'.
2.  Running pass 'Prologue/Epilogue Insertion & Frame Finalization' on function '@_T04Milq20AnswerViewControllerC28didTapOverFlowMenuOpenrationyAA0ghI10OperationsO13menuOperation_tF

func didTapOverFlowMenuOpenration ()
```

once i make change to this function in the class error pointed to, code compiles but same function in other class does not give any compilation error.

tried all solution from this - [Already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724897/command-failed-due-to-signal-abort-trap-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Have you tried a clean build? Also, what exactly is the error?

Comment: What is the entire crash log?

Comment: @staticVoidMan too long to put here.

Comment: @Palle Yes i cleaned the derived data many times. There is no specific error in code, but while compiling the code in the error log i get above stated 1 and 2 point listed.

Comment: Try to strip down a copy of your project to a minimal reproducible example and then post the code here.

Comment: I was able to compile my code with Xcode 9.3 if I change the Swift Compiler Optimization level to [-O] (Optimize for speed), But not sure why it worked and Why it didn't if Optimization level was [-Onone]

Comment: Updating to Xcode 9.4 fixed it.