# How to solve "Abort trap: 6" in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, xcode, simulator

I have a project in swift which was working very well but today I tried to run it on simulator and I got 101 errors for many of my classes which says "error: Abort trap: 6". When I try to run it on my iPhone it works fine but it has errors for simulators. I tried to search and read many links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724897/command-failed-due-to-signal-abort-trap-6) but nothing solved my problem. Anyone faced same issue?

Comment: Try clean/clean build folder, and delete your derived data

Comment: @SanderSaelmans tried that but still not working

Comment: Having too many errors means you are using a third party SDK and which is not building properly. Fixing the first error will fix all other issues. Can you please share more logs of the errors from build logs which files are exactly causing this issue and why a screen shot would also help.

Comment: Can u share error screenshot from Xcode?

Comment: Same issue here, this seems to be a compiler bug, try to write your last piece of added code differently.