# Xcode compiling error "error abort trap 6"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode10, xcode10.2

My proyect compiled well til update to xcode 10.2. And now when I try to compile, I got the "**error: Abort trap: 6**"

- I found this message, but I'm not sure if this is the problem: "LLVM 
  ERROR: out of memory "
- I've already tried to change the optimization level to none and the
  debug information format to DWAFT with dSYM file but it didn't work
  for me.
- Also I've tried to re install the Xcode

I found this:

```
1.  While emitting IR SIL function "@$sypIegn_Ieg_TR".
 for <<debugloc at "<compiler-generated>":0:0>>0  swift                    0x000000010c13cee3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x000000010c13c6bc SignalHandler(int) + 348
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7071db5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000115e7cf87 _sigtramp + 2775970887
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff705dd6a6 abort + 127
5  swift                    0x000000010c0ed644 llvm::report_bad_alloc_error(char const*, bool) + 100
6  swift                    0x000000010800b210 swift::irgen::CallEmission::setArgs(swift::irgen::Explosion&, bool, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*) + 2560
7  swift                    0x00000001081bf335 (anonymous namespace)::IRGenSILFunction::visitFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 2053
8  swift                    0x000000010819f6aa swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 9898
9  swift                    0x000000010805e259 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitLazyDefinitions() + 1353
10 swift                    0x000000010817cdd7 swift::performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 1895
11 swift                    0x0000000107fa1030 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 49280
12 swift                    0x0000000107f916de swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6862
13 swift                    0x0000000107f2f7be main + 1246
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff705383d5 start + 1
error: Abort trap: 6
```

And the log, end in this way:

```
/Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/views/Portfolio/PortfolioBarChart.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/views/Menu/MenuCell.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/Model/MarketStatus/MarketStatus.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/Model/MarketTime.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/views/Menu/AccountCell.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/views/Common/LabelImageCell.swift /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios/app-ios/Converter/PriceDepthItemConverter.swift -output-file-map /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/app-ios-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/app_ios.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/app-ios-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/app-ios-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/app-ios-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/app-ios-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-ios-hjlqbhxpptzultcjcyzoxjdodfod/Build/Intermediates.noindex/app-ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/app-ios.build/Objects-normal/arm64/app_ios-Swift.h -working-directory /Users/user/repos/xxx-ios

<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Abort trap: 6
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 6 (use -v to see invocation)





<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Abort trap: 6
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 6 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what can be causing the error 6?

Thanks

Comment: I face this issue before, could you tell me what pods do you install ?

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724897/command-failed-due-to-signal-abort-trap-6 hope it will help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724897/command-failed-due-to-signal-abort-trap-6)

Answer (score 2):

Problem: Abort Trap (In my case my code is working perfectly but when I trying to make an Archive for upload app on test flight[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NnH4.jpg) file I got the "Abort Trap")

Solution:- Just Select Your Project from project Navegater (most Left Pane)  Select Project > Select Targets > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Genration > Optimization Level > Debug and Realease make "No Optimization [-Onone]"