# how to fix error: Abort trap 6 (in target 'RealmSwift' from project 'Pods')?

Tags: swift, xcode

when building the project, an error appears error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'RealmSwift' from project 'Pods')

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Uog.png

I am using xcode 13.3, macbook on m1 pro

The tips I found on the internet didn't help.

Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

Comment: Did you succeed to solve the problem ? I have the same issue and I'm completely stuck :(

Comment: **See what fixed it for me:** [Command failed due to signal: Abort trap: 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30724897/8740349)

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue you need to update the Realm version that you have to the RealmSwift 10.25.0 or over.

You can change the Podfile file

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 10.25.0'
```

After that you just need to open the Terminal in your project folder and do:

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: I have updated Realm to 10.28.1 , then it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after Xcode update.
This command did help:

pod repo update

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, hope it could be useful :)

Select Pods > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Genration > Optimization Level > Debug and Realease make "No Optimization [-Onone]"

Select Your Project > Select Targets > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Genration > Optimization Level > Debug and Realease make "No Optimization [-Onone]"