# couldn't solve error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'RealmSwift' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I tried cleaning the project folder, deleting derived data, sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi cmd
nothing seems to work

Comment: The problem mentioned here [how to fix error: Abort trap 6 (in target 'RealmSwift' from project 'Pods')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699020/how-to-fix-error-abort-trap-6-in-target-realmswift-from-project-pods)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.